# FFmpeg slideshow concat outputs only the last image

Tags: ffmpeg

I'am trying to produce image slideshow by ffmpeg concat.
The problem is that the output video only plays the last image from my input file with images.

The input:

```
file '/var/www/html/docroot/types/video/images/img0.jpg'
duration 10
file '/var/www/html/docroot/types/video/images/img1.jpg'
duration 10
file '/var/www/html/docroot/types/video/images/img2.jpg'
duration 10
```

The command:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 1/10 -f concat -safe 0 -i /var/www/html/docroot/types/video/info.txt -c:v libx264 -vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2,fps=30,format=yuv420p" /var/www/html/docroot/types/video/output.mp4
```

And in the output I have something like this:
[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPwog.gif)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `-r 1/10` and `,fps=30`:

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i /var/www/html/docroot/types/video/info.txt -c:v libx264 -vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2,format=yuv420p" /var/www/html/docroot/types/video/output.mp4
```